# What are the differences between Lettuce and Pyccuracy?

Tags: testing, bdd, lettuce, pyccuracy

Can someone with experience using both [Lettuce](http://lettuce.it) and [Pyccuracy](http://pyccuracy.org) describe their differences both in terms of features and uses?

From the [Lettuce Overview](http://lettuce.it/intro/overview.html#intro-overview) documentation:

> Lettuce is a very simple BDD tool based on Cucumber, which currently has many more features than Lettuce.
>
> Lettuce aims the most common tasks on BDD and it focus specially on those that make BDD so fun :)
>
> Provide to the developers the ability of describing features in a natural language, by creating one or more scenarios.

From the [Pyccuracy](http://pyccuracy.org) github page:

> Pyccuracy is a Behaviour-Driven-Development-style tool written in Python that aims to make it easier to write automated acceptance tests. It improves the readability of those tests by using a structured natural language – and a simple mechanism to extend this language – so that both developers and customers can collaborate and understand what the tests do.

Answer (score 3):

Pyccuracy uses the Gherkin DSL to drive Selenium tests. That is, UI tests through a browser.

Lettuce uses the Gherkin DSL to drive what are sometimes called 'subcutaneous' acceptance tests. That is, tests of your domain layer independent of the UI.